# Clarification on measurability and a particular set cover

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

**Preamble:** Suppose that $m^*$ is the Radon outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Define $r_i^*(S) = (m^*|B_i(0))(S) = m^*(S\cap B_i(0)), S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ the restriction of $m^*$ to the open ball of radius $i$ centered at the origin. Assume it to be known that 1.) $r_i^*$ is a Radon outer measure, and $r_i^*(\mathbb{R}^n) \leq m^*(\overline{B_i(0)}) < \infty$, 2.) for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists closed set $C$ and open set $D$ such that $C \subseteq S \subseteq D$, $m^*(S\setminus C) < \epsilon, m^*(D\setminus S) < \epsilon$, 3.) if the set $S$ is $m^*$-measurable (by Caratheodory's criterion), then it is also $r_i^*$-measurable.

Then, there exists open sets $S \subseteq D_i$ such that $r_i^*(D_i\setminus S) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}$, $i = 1,2,\dots$. Define $D = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty(D_i \cap B_i(0))$.

**Main question:** What I am struggling to understand is that why $S \subset D$? We certainly know that $S$ belongs to every $D_i$. But what "guarantee" there is that $S$ belongs to the intersection of $D_i$ with the open ball $B_i(0)$? My reading material does not provide any further information about this, and proceeds onwards with the surrounding proof about a property of Radon outer measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x\in S$ and find $i$ so large that $|x|<i$. Then $x\in D_i\cap B(0,i)$.